# thrust::sequence - how to increase the step after each N elements

Tags: cuda, copy, sequence, thrust

I am using

```
thrust::sequence(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 0, 1)
```

and achieve good ordered list like:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

My question is how can I achieve such a list below (the best way?)

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 ,2, 3, 3, 3
```

I know how to make it with functors, so please do not try to answer it with functor. I want to learn if there is an optimized way for it in Thrust, or am I missing a simple way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> myvector(N);

thrust::transform( thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                   thrust::make_counting_iterator(N),
                   thrust::make_constant_iterator(3),
                   myvector.begin(),
                   thrust::divides<int>() );
```

(disclaimer, written in browser, never compiled or tested, use at own risk)

should give you the sequence you are looking for by computing `[0..N]//3` and outputting the result on `myvector`.

---

Seeing as you are having trouble compiling your version, here is a complete example which compiles and runs:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    const int N = 18, M = 3;
    thrust::device_vector<int> myvector(N);

    thrust::transform(  thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                        thrust::make_counting_iterator(N),
                        thrust::make_constant_iterator(M),
                        myvector.begin(),
                        thrust::divides<int>() );

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int val = myvector[i];
        printf("%d %d\n", i, val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer but I could not be able to compile: xyz.cu(544): error: no instance of overloaded function "thrust::transform" matches the argument list argument types are: (thrust::counting_iterator<int, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default>, thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default>, thrust::constant_iterator<unsigned int, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>, thrust::divides<int>)

Comment: Did you read the error message? You have mixed `unsigned int` and `int` types for the constant and counting iterators arguments. I have edited the answer with a compilable example which runs correctly for you to study.

Comment: yes, I was amazed as getting such an error and missed the unsigned int vs int mismatch. Nice catch, both the answer and the error. thank you.

Comment: yes I found the error, in my case, N and M was unsigned int. So the constant_iterator, and counting iterator was producing unsigned int iterators. interesting :)